# Regex match only if a word in the string is starting with the substring

Tags: regex

How to define a regex matcher capable of detecting if any word in string is starting with the substring. Test cases for  "me":

```
"My name is" -> False
"I like meditation" -> True
"Me and my dog" -> True
"I want more fake-news-media" -> False
```

Comment: i.e you want to match 'me' at either the start of the string or if it immediately follows whitespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
/(^| )me/
```

It wants to either have the string start with `me` or there needs to be a space in front of `me`.  Another option may be:

```
/\bme/
```

which would leverage word boundaries, but then your 4th example would be `True` and it looks like you don't want that.

Demo:

https://regex101.com/r/VWAZwK/2

Make sure to have your regex have `ignore case` enabled.

Answer (score 0):

something like this :

```
/^(me)/i
```

?